# Process custom elements specified in returned json

Tags: aurelia

I have a custom Aurelia that can be invoked like

Test

This works fine using in a html page in the site.

However, I have some restful services that return html with these custom
elements. I then use this html as content in my Aurelia site. At this point the custom elements won't execute. This there a way to tell Aurelia to process the custom elements in the returned html before display ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a combination of `<compose>` and `InlineViewStrategy`.

Gist demo: https://gist.run/?id=bd1122986ba8dabde8111c3b4ab6df6f

The main idea here is to have a custom component, which is able to use the  html extracted from returned JSON result. With `InlineViewStrategy`, it's possible to get a full-featured template parser on-the-fly and to feed `<compose>` with it.
This way that chunk of html will be treated as any other part of the application. It can contain other custom elements as well.

### Custom Element

Basically, it's just an extended `<compose>`, but for `view` bindable property it accepts a string variable instead of a view path.

**part.html**

```
<template>
  <compose view.bind="viewStrategy" model.bind="model"></compose>
</template>
```

**part.js**

```
import {inject, bindable, InlineViewStrategy} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Api} from './api'; // REST of your magic goes here

@inject(Api)
export class Part {

  // template string
  @bindable view;

  // data model
  @bindable model;

  // rest api url (optional)
  @bindable templateHref;

  constructor(api) { 
    this.api = api;
  } 

  // render html template
  viewChanged() {
    if (this.view) {
      this.viewStrategy = new InlineViewStrategy(this.view);
    }
  }

  // load html from remote url (optional feature)
  templateHrefChanged() {
    if (this.templateHref) {
      this.api
        .loadTemplate(this.templateHref)
        .then(result => {
          this.view = result.content;
        });
    }
  }
}
```

### Usage

**remote api processing**

```
// api call goes here

// JSON result could be similar to this
result = {
    content: 
        `<template>
          <require from="./custom-part"></require>

          <h2>${model.title}</h2>
          <custom-part title.bind="model.title"></custom-part>
          <p>${model.content}</p>
        </template>`,

    error: false
};

this.testView = result.content;
```

**app.html**

Load template string from a variable

`<part view.bind="testView" model.bind="testModel"></part>`

Load template from an url

`<part template-href="http://remote-api-url" model.bind="{title: 'Another...', content: '...'}"></part>`

Load template from a non-existing url

`<part template-href="./remote-api-notfound" model.bind="testModel"></part>`

---

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks that works. I added <template> and '<require from="./components/shimmy_dialog"></require>' dynamically to the returned html as I don't wont the restful service to have those.